# Nested Navigators

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Main navigator in app is tab-navigator, in it i have a drawer-navigator and in drawer i have stack-navigator because my home screen wants tab,drawer and stack navigators

but i have another screen that's no need more stack and tab in it !!
where should i place the screen to hide both stack and tab?

```
const stackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    ...
});
const drawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    home: { screen: stackNavigator }, 
    ...
)}
const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    home: { screen: drawerNavigator },
    ...
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to dynamically hide the bottom navigator as well as the header bar by defining `headerMode: 'none'` and `tabBarVisible: false` in the screens' navigationOptions object.

Find out more by reading the documentation for [StackNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#docsNav) and [BottomTabNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html#docsNav).

Comment: Thanks for answer but i only can modify navigation options for a navigator from one of its screen components,that’s problem